# How do I copy over this string into my new char type

Tags: c++

here's what I have I only get the first letter of the word in Fam and given
how do I get the whole string inside?

```
void CRA_Account::set(const char * familyName, const char * givenName, int sin)
    {

    if (sin > min_sin && sin < max_sin) {

        Fam = *familyName;
        given = *givenName;


        sin1 = sin;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Why is it a `const char*`? Isn't that limited to one char?

Comment: `*familyName` == `familyName[0]`: the first character.

Comment: @Annabelle - no it isn't.

Comment: @Annabelle char* is a pointer to a char, but it can also be a pointer to the first element of an array of chars, aka a C style string.

Answer (score 1):

`familyName` is a pointer to a character object. When you dereference the pointer, the result is the pointed character.

> How do I copy over this string
>
> how do I get the whole string inside?

First you need to figure out, where you want to store the copy of the string. A character object for example, cannot store a string of many characters.

A reasonable way to store a string is `std::string` object. Copying a null terminated string into a `std::string` is as simple as passing the pointer to the constructor, or the assignment operator:

```
std::string Fam;

// later
Fam = familyName;
```

Comment: how would I output it on cout?

Comment: @MarcoPastore you can use the stream insertion operation.